# How do I place an image below a number or below the letter in parts?

Tags: formatting

I am using the following latex to create an exam with multiple parts :

```
\question Find the length of each arc.
\begin{parts}
    \part \includegraphics[]{17.png}

    \vspace{1in}
    \part \includegraphics[]{18.png}
\end{parts}
```

but the image is being printed above the letter, is there a way to make the image print below the letter.

[image]

Comment: Add `\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}` to your preamble, and then use `\includegraphics[valign=t]{17.png}`.

Comment: That worked!! thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`adjustbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox) provides `export`ed key-value options to [`graphicx`](//ctan.org/pkg/graphicx), including the use of a `v`ertical `align`ment key. Specifying a `t`op alignment should work in your setup. That is,

```
\question Find the length of each arc.
\begin{parts}
    \part \includegraphics[valign=t]{17.png}

    \vspace{1in}
    \part \includegraphics[valign=t]{18.png}
\end{parts}
```